# Does JSON have a +json suffix convention?

Tags: xml, json, mime-types, rfc

XML has a convention whereby non-standard mime types based on XML take on a '+xml' suffix (useful for syntax-highlighting, etc). This is outlined by [RFC3023](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3023).

I've taken a look at [RFC4626](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt) but I can't find any mention of something similar for JSON. Does JSON have a similar convention? Is it documented anywhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes the +json suffix is described in the following RFC:
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6839

Comment: Maybe you could expand your answer, at the moment it amounts to little more than a link.

Answer (score 2):

XML has a variety of media types out there. Some common ones are:

- **XHTML** (extensible hypertext markup language) `application/xhtml+xml`
- **SVG** (scalable vector graphics) `image/svg+xml`
- **RSS** (really simple syndication) `application/rss+xml`

Each MIME type identifies a different language.

[RFC 3023](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3023#section-3) standardizes the convention of using the suffix +xml as rightly pointed out by you.

Paraphrased from the wikipedia article - [XML and MIME](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_and_MIME).

**Update:** Removed incorrect assumption that JSON is not used as an alternative representation for XML.

There are alternate MIME types with suffix `+json` being widely used. And as rightly pointed out these will continue grow considering JSON.

The `+json` suffix convention is non-standard, but being used by others.

Comment: I don't think this is true -- there is growing number of formats based on JSON, similar to how XML (meta-language) is used to define things like XHTML, SVG and RSS. For example, activity streams format has both XML and JSON base variants; geoJSON is used quite widely, and number will grow.

Answer (score 2):

There is an ongoing specification process for `"application/" subtype "+json"` in [A JSON Media Type for Describing the Structure and Meaning of JSON Documents](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-zyp-json-schema-03) in draft status writing this. Further resources are available at http://json-schema.org/.

Comment: The JSON Schema specification does not actually define a `+json` suffix contention. The specification just happens to refer to a `application/schema+json` mime type but that isn't the same.

Comment: Wow. I have no idea what I was thinking. You're right, the attached draft *does* define a `+json` suffix.

Answer (score 1):

The GitHub API uses custom JSON mime types.

http://developer.github.com/v3/media/

You could adopt their conventions.

I don't think it's been documented in the same way as custom XML mime types have. I think it's useful, though, and that it ought to be documented. In the meantime you can use them, and understand that some tools won't recognize the mime type as JSON.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen such convention being used, yes. This is not something JSON (the specification) has to specify, although maybe later revisions could suggest guidelines. Most likely it would be defined as a separate RFC.

You might want to ask this question on a mailing list such as [restful-json](http://groups.google.com/group/restful-json?pli=1), where there are more experts who could give more complete answer.